# Drop a borrow reference while keeping the underlying allocated memory

Tags: memory, rust, borrow-checker

Imagine in this case, I basically store data on the heap.

```rust
let layout = Layout::new::<usize>();
let data: usize = 1;
let data_ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut usize;
ptr::write(data_ptr, data);
let data_ref = &mut *data_ptr;
```

Now if I'd like to reuse the same memory to store something else, I can just write another data to `data_ptr`.

```rust
let data2: usize = 2;
ptr::write(data_ptr, data2);
let data2_ref = &mut *data_ptr;
// `data1_ref` is still valid
```

However, `data_ref` is still valid under the same scope. How can I invalid `data_ref` at the language level to make sure it cannot access the allocated memory?

Comment: You forgot to add the definition of `layout`. As well as the use statements. Ideally you'd create a [mre] which can be run by copy & pasting.

Comment: Abstract it into a associated function on a struct holding a phantom mutable lifetime.

Comment: @cafce25 I don't think the definition of `layout` is needed here, it is obviously `std::alloc::Layout`.

Comment: The definitions while not strictly necessary would still disambiguate and thus increase the value of this question. @IvanC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that I would consider to be fairly idiomatic:

```rust
use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};

struct Wrapper(*mut usize);

impl Wrapper {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let inner = unsafe { alloc(Layout::new::<usize>()).cast() };
        Self(inner)
    }

    fn write(&mut self, data: usize) {
        unsafe { self.0.write(data) }
    }

    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut usize {
        unsafe { &mut *self.0 }
    }
}
```

This ensures that one can not hold on to a ref returned by `as_mut` after calling `write` by tying lifetime of `&mut usize` to the lifetime of `self`:

```rust
    fn as_mut(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut usize {
        unsafe { &mut *self.0 }
    }
```

Note that if your actual data is more complicated, you have to implement `Drop` for your wrapper, which can be done like this:

```rust
use std::{
    alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout},
    ptr::drop_in_place,
};

struct HasDrop {
    // Struct that owns some resources
}

struct Wrapper {
    inner: *mut HasDrop,
    init: bool,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let inner = unsafe { alloc(Layout::new::<HasDrop>()).cast() };
        Self { inner, init: false }
    }

    fn write(&mut self, data: HasDrop) {
        unsafe { self.inner.write(data) }
        self.init = true;
    }

    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut HasDrop {
        unsafe { &mut *self.inner }
    }
}

impl Drop for Wrapper {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            if self.init {
                drop_in_place(self.inner);
            }
            dealloc(self.inner.cast(), Layout::new::<HasDrop>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: they should `impl Drop for Wrapper` to automatically deallocate.

Comment: @PitaJ good comment, added an example of that for completeness' sake

Comment: The drop code you added doesn't free the allocation. Also I wouldn't have `write` + `new` and instead merge the two so you never have an uninit state.

Comment: Thanks yall. Both comments are very insightful!